# Is there any dictionary look-up frequency list?

Tags: dictionaries, frequency-analysis

The Online Portuguese Dictionary **Dicio** offers a (arbitrarily long) [list](https://www.dicio.com.br/palavras-mais-buscadas/2/) of words ordered by look-up frequency. I find such a list very useful when selecting words to learn as a native speaker because the words that top the list are common (i.e., useful) enough that many native speakers meet them in their daily activities, but are at the same time rare enough that the same native speakers feel the need to look up their meanings.

Is there such a list for English?

I performed a cursory search online, but was only able to find very small lists for the most well-known online dictionaries. I imagine that Wiktionary would offer such information, but I was again not able to find anything promising.

Comment: An interesting question, Bourbaki, but it will be transferred to the ELUMeta site, being a request for a resource. Hopefully, it will get an anwer there. A complication that springs to mind is that your analysis perhaps tacitly presupposes a _one word  ↔ one meaning / usage_ correspondence. But someone might look up 'be' for instance, to find how it's being used in 'If I be found guilty' ('present subjunctive'), or try to find why we use 'on' in the phrase 'on fire', or look up the commonly used 'without' after singing the Easter hymn 'There is a green hill far away / without a city wall ...'.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, Edwin. I understand. I apologize for asking this in an inappropriate place. The lack of a one meaning ⇔ one word correspondence is a problem one must always face when processing natural language using a dictionary, as unfortunately there isn't any corpus whose words are annotated with their corresponding meaning/usage as described in an open-source dictionary (i.e., Wiktionary) available. But I still think I can get some useful data/resources, albeit on a lower resolution, even if I ignore such issues.